# Binding keypress event on knockoutjs, observable not populated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Need a little help with knockoutjs and binding a keypress event. I'm trying to hook up knockout so that I pick up on the enter keypress from within a text box. So I can perform the same action as clicking a button. Its a little tricky to explain but hopefully this JsFiddle will demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/nbnML/8/

The problem I have is that observable value is not getting updated and I think its something to do with an observable not being updated until focus moves away from the textbox?

Any solutions to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

One option is to use the `valueUpdate` additional binding to force an update on each keypress.  For example, you would do:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: InputValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: RunSomethingKey }" />
```

If that is not what you are after, then really you would want to fire the element's change event in your handler.  For example with jQuery, you would do something like: `$(event.target).change();`.

It would be better though to move this into a custom binding.  Maybe something like (probably should check if the result of valueAccessor() is a function):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterKey = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                ko.utils.triggerEvent(element, "change");
                valueAccessor().call(vm, vm); //set "this" to the data and also pass it as first arg, in case function has "this" bound
            }

            return true;
        });
    }         
};
```

Here is your sample updated: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/nbnML/9/

Comment: Awesome answer. However on firefox pressing Enter on the textbox leads to the event firing twice. Any helpful thoughts there please?

Comment: @Nikhil - probably need to do something like `e.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: @RP - This saved me!  Thanks for posting this!  I noticed it does break if you add fields, put KO data-bindings on them, but forget to add them to the ViewModel.  But that was my own mistake during implementation and probably breaks KO, anyway, when you do that.  But just wanted to note for anyone that might wonder if it's this code, or something they're doing while using it, that causes it to break - that it's probably them!  Thanks, again.

Comment: I noticed when I ran this that I didn't need the `valueAccessor().call()` statement, though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't discount submit bindings:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html

This takes care of some IE 9/10 gotchas such as the return key not updating the observable. With this taken care of you don't need to intercept keycode 13

html:

```
<form data-bind="submit:RunSomething">
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: InputValue" />
 <input type="submit" value="test" />
 <div data-bind="text: InputValue" />
</form>
```

code:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.InputValue = ko.observable('');

    self.RunSomething = function (ev) {
        window.alert(self.InputValue());
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

See this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jnewcomb/uw2WX/