# Update observable bound to input value only on enter key press

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a text field that is bound to an observable:

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="value: chartOptions.zoomLevel" value="100%" />
```

This works fine, except that the field needs to lose focus before the observable is updated. What I need is to update that the observable only changes when the enter key is pressed.

I've looked at [the possible valueUpdate parameters](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html), but none of them seem to be suitable.

Comment: just realised you wanted enter key press rather than any key press, but I'll leave my answer there for the time being in case it's useful. Here's a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628789/binding-keypress-event-on-knockoutjs-observable-not-populated

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087721/call-function-on-enter-key-press-knockout-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a way to do this with [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), but here's a straightforward way to do it using [the `event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html). You seem to imply that the observable should *only* change iif the enter key is pressed. However, I've added the `blur` event as a trigger too; it's easy to remove that anyhow.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.zoomLevel = ko.observable('100');
  self.newZoomLevel = ko.observable('100');
  
  self.tryCommitZoomLevel = function(data, event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.type === "blur") {
      self.zoomLevel(event.target.value);
    }
    
    // Make sure the event bubbles to let the value binding also handle events:
    return true;
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="event: { keypress: tryCommitZoomLevel, blur: tryCommitZoomLevel }, value: newZoomLevel" />
<br />
The zoom level you've entered is: <strong data-bind="text: zoomLevel"></strong>%
```

The snippet keeps a seperate "new value" copy of the actual observable, and only commits it if the user presses enter or the input looses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a polyfill that may help - forces IE to fire 'change' event on `enter` key (as other browsers do) which in turn triggers Knockout's `value` binding.

```
var isIE = !!document.documentMode;
if (isIE) {

    $("body").on("keydown", "input[type='text']", function (e) {

        // Ensure 'value' binding is fired on enter in IE
        if ((e.keyCode || e.which) === 13) {
            $(this).blur();
        }
    });
}
```